# Names of the f suborbitals. (Reference Request)

Tags: orbitals, reference-request

Today, I have been browsing the internet to know the names of the "f" orbitals. But I have varying answers on the web. Different sources seem to be stating different names. Like here,
[image: Ref1]

and here

[image: Ref2]

Besides the first 2 pictures, [this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-7-F-orbitals) also gives different names.

By names, I mean names of suborbitals like $d_{xy}$, $d_{z^2}$ etc.

Right now, I am really confused. An answer with a solid reference would definitely make my day.

Comment: What does "*name*" mean here? And please don't educate yourself on the internet with random Google images.

Comment: By saying "name", I am talking about like d(xy) and d(z^2) etc. It wasn't included in my textbook, that's why I googled it.

Comment: The reason you see different labels is that the set of real orbitals is not unique. It depends on what combination of the spherical harmonics you use to form each orbital. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_harmonic